# decode base64 image fail after retrive from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, cordova

May it easy. But i can't figure it out. 
I am using cordova camera plugin which give me direct base64 data like following..

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL});

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    $('#userFullProfileImage').attr('src', "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);
}
```

It is working. Because it shows me the image after set source of **userFullProfileImage.** So encoding is correct.

Now, i am trying to save **imageData** in mysql and retrieve it via ajax.

After retrieve i match several line and found no mistake. **imageData** before save and **imageData** after retrieve seems to me same ( But save data omit all  **+** character)

Retrieved image data can't decode. I use online base64 decoder too. But no hope. May be missing  **+** character is for this reason.

I have checked all other character, line by line,  both of **imageData** are same.

So now help me, which could be the possible reasons in my case.

Comment: There are many online tools to compare two strings. Be sure at least than both strings are same

Comment: There is a problem. Output file is only in alert(imageData) format in mobile. There is no any print format as i use them after closing this app. camera plugin only work in mobile. No browser base support. So i write manually some data and take screenshot (they seems to be same). But now i realize they might not be same at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was during send image data through ajax.

```
encodeURIComponent(imageData); //This solve my problem.
```

Encoded data is now safely save in database.

After retrieve from encoded data from database i have just used another function.

```
decodeURIComponent(encodedData); //same of imageData
```

Answer (score 1):

If your + characters are being stripped, it sounds like it's going through a URL encoding scheme, which could convert + to spaces, which could then be ignored as whitespace by the base64 decoder. This could be happening as part of your AJAX request, which defaults to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

If you say that you're going to submit url encoded data, then don't encode it, it will be incorrectly decoded by the server on receipt.

Try setting your content type in the AJAX request e.g.

```
$.post({
    url: yourUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify(yourBase64string),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Where contentType will tell the server that you're submitting your data as JSON and dataType will tell the server what format you expect the response to be in (so in this case the server should send its response in JSON, but you could also use a dataType of e.g. "text")

You could alternatively use a contentType of "text/plain" and remove the JSON.stringify but I have not tested this.